# How to factor all coefficients of a multivariable into prime factors

Tags: evaluation, polynomials, coefficients

I have several polynomials in 2 variables with integer coefficients, e.g.,

```
poly= -10 x - 10240 y^3 - 1520 x y^4;
```

I'd like to convert all such polynomials into a form in which the coefficients have been factored into prime factors. So the above example would become

```
polyf= -2 5 x - 2^11 5 y^3 - 2^4 5 19 x y^4;
```

I can do this case by case, by using

```
FactorInteger
```

but it is inefficient for a large collection of polynomials. So I did some searching and found that a possible solution is to use

```
cpoly = FactorInteger[GroebnerBasis`DistributedTermsList[poly, , {x, y}][[1, All, -1]]];
```

The output is

```
{{{-1, 1}, {2, 4}, {5, 1}, {19, 1}}, {{-1, 1}, {2, 1}, {5, 1}}, {{-1, 1}, {2, 11}, {5, 1}}}
```

But I can't work out how to thread this back to give me the answer I wanted. Ideas like

```
poly x^Range[0, Exponent[poly, x]] y^Range[0, Exponent[poly, y]]
```

don't give the results I wanted. Instead they lead to

```
(-10 x - 10240 y^3 - 1520 x y^4) {1, x} {1, y, y^2, y^3, y^4}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have developed an better alternative code you may be interested in. I added it to my original answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could create a `factoredForm` wrapper that formats integers as desired:

```
MakeBoxes[factoredForm[e_], StandardForm] := Block[{$Factored=True},
    MakeBoxes[e]
]

Unprotect[Integer];

MakeBoxes[i_Integer, form_] /; $Factored := Block[{$Factored},
    TemplateBox[
        {RowBox[tosuperscript /@ FactorInteger[i]], MakeBoxes[i]},
        "FactoredInteger",
        DisplayFunction->(#1&),
        InterpretationFunction->(#2&)
    ]
]

tosuperscript[{-1, 1}] := "-"
tosuperscript[{a_, 1}] := MakeBoxes[a]
tosuperscript[{a_, b_}] := MakeBoxes[a^b]

Unprotect[Power];

MakeBoxes[Power[a_, i_Integer], StandardForm] /; $Factored := With[
    {exp = Block[{$Factored}, RawBoxes @ MakeBoxes[i]]},
    MakeBoxes[Power[a, exp]]
]

Protect[Integer, Power];
```

Some examples:

```
-10 x - 10240 y^3 - 1520 x y^4 //factoredForm
```

> [image: -25 x-2^11 5 y^3-2^4 519 x y^4]

```
 (21 x^10 + 35 x^4 y^12)(-10 x - 10240 y^3 - 1520 x y^4) //factoredForm
```

> [image: (-25 x-2^11 5 y^3-2^4 519 x y^4) (37 x^10+57 x^4 y^12)]

```
25 y (20 + 160 x^4 y^4 + 5 x^6 y^5) //factoredForm
```

> [image]

Comment: Wow. This is wonderful. It overcomes the problem in the second example I provided above. And, most wonderfully, it also works for 3 variable polynomials: `(-25 y + 16 z)(-10 x - 10240 y^3 - 1520 x y^4)` gives the desired answer (which I can't seem to cut and paste here). Thank you so much!

Comment: Although I've used Mathematica for a long time, it's clear to me that I'm a very naive user of it. Can you recommend references that progresses to a level of technical knowledge on how to write such wrappers?

Answer (score 3):

Another simple solution is to use pattern matching to find all the integer coefficients, `FactorInteger` them, and then reassemble the number but using an `Inactive` version of `Power` which doesn't evaluate.

```
InactiveFactorization[i_] := Inactive[Times] @@ (Inactive[Power] @@@ FactorInteger[i])
factorpolycoeffs = {
  i_Integer?Positive (e : x_Symbol^y_Integer | x_Symbol) :> InactiveFactorization[i] e,
  i_Integer?Negative (e : x_Symbol^y_Integer | x_Symbol) :> -InactiveFactorization[-i] e
}
cleanupprimepowers = {Inactive[Power][x_Integer, 1] -> x}
```

Here we explicitly address the positive and negative case to avoid an uglier factorization of negative coefficients and zeros by `FactorInteger`. Now we can use these rules to factor our

```
poly = -10 x - 10240 y^3 - 1520 x y^4;

(poly /. factorpolycoeffs)
% /. cleanupprimepowers
```

> -x 2^1 5^1-y^3 2^11 5^1-x y^4 2^4 5^1 19^1
>
> -x (2*5)-y^3 (2^11*5)-x y^4 (2^4*5*19)

We can `Activate` the `Power` and `Times` terms in the expression to let the kernel resolve the expression to the original `poly`

```
Activate[%]
```

> -10 x-10240 y^3-1520 x y^4

**Edit** I added a second rule to simplify prime powers of one to make the result more readable which also required to `Inactive`ate `Times`, too.

Comment: Unfortunately, the answer is not quite what I needed. For example, the first term should be `-2*5 x` rather than `-10 x`. But thank you.

Comment: Oh, true! Thanks for pointing that out. Didn't think about the case where there are prime powers of one. I edited my answer and fixed that case!

Comment: Thanks for the fast response... Unfortunately, I think I prefer the factored coefficients to come before the variables, so that I can easily convert to LaTeX output, but this is useful.

Comment: I understand, no worries! I just thought this method isn't covered by the other answers and simple enough that it might be the easiest solution in some situations.

Answer (score 2):

The following functions using `Rule[]` and `Interpretation[]`:

```
fi[n_] := Times @@ (FactorInteger[n] /. {
  List[-1, 1] -> -1, 
  List[p_Integer, 1] :> Interpretation[ToString[p], p], 
  List[p_Integer, q_Integer] :> 
    Interpretation[ToString[p]^q, p^q]});
do[e_] := e /. {x_. n_Integer :> x fi[n],
             x_^y_. n_Integer :> x^y fi[n]};
```

used in an example code

```
 do[ (21 x^10 +35 x^4 y^12)(-10 x -10240 y^3 -1520 x y^4) ]
```

returns something very close to what you want.

The downside is that the numerical factored coefficients come *after*
the powered variables and not *before*.There may be a way to fix that
but I don't see it now. The advantage of using `Interpretation[]` is
that you can copy/paste the resulting output and it evaluates the same
as the original polynomial.

**NEW:**

I developed an **alternate** approach which does a much better job.

```
fi[n_Integer] := Sign[n] With[{fl = FactorInteger@Abs@n}, fl /.
   {List[1, 1] -> 1, List[p_Integer, 1] :> ToString[p], 
   List[p_Integer, q_Integer] :> (ToString[p])^q} /.
   {List[x_] :> x, List[x__] :> Inactive@Times@x}];
do[ex_] := Activate //@ (x_^n_Integer :> x^n, 
   n_Integer :> fi[n], n_Integer* x_. :> fi[n] x});
```

For example:

```
do[(21 x^10 +35 x^4 y^12) (-10 x -10240 y^3 -1520 x y^4)] // TeXForm
```

returns the result

```
\left(-19 2^4 5 x y^4+2^{11} (-5) y^3-2 5 x\right) \left(3 7 x^{10}+5 7 x^4 y^{12}\right)
```

which exposes a "misfeature" of `TeXForm[]`. For exmaple: `TeXForm[-1-x^2 z]` returns "x^2 (-z)-1".

The new code only requires `Activate[]`, `Inactive[]` and a tweaked `fi[]`. It avoids the downside in the original method. It avoids the need to add rules to system objects `Power` and `Integer` which has global scope.

Comment: This is a fantastic start. Thank you

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution doesn't seem to work when `poly` is a factored polynomial containing only one variable. E.g., `25 y (20 + 160 x^4 y^4 + 5 x^6 y^5)` is transformed to `y (20 + 160 x^4 y^4 + 5 x^6 y^5) 5^2`. So the coefficient of the first factor is expressed in terms of its prime factors but the next factor is not.

Comment: Thank you for responding to my comment. I agree it works now and it also extends to more variables. (I tried `(-25 y + 16 z)*(-10 x - 10240 y^3 - 1520 x y^4)`.) I think I prefer the factored coefficients to come _before_ the variables, so that I can easily convert to LaTeX output, but thank you anyway.

Answer (score 2):

If it's just for display purposes, you could define something like

```
fi[z_Integer /; z > 0] := Times @@ Subscript @@@ FactorInteger[z]
fi[z_Integer /; z < 0] := -fi[-z]
fi[1] = 1;
```

Inert mechanisms other than `Subscript` could be used for this purpose. The last definition `fi[1] = 1` is a matter of taste, to make terms like `x^3` become $x^3$ instead of $1_1x^3$.

Apply it to the coefficients of a polynomial `poly` in variables `vars`

```
poly = -10 x - 10240 y^3 - 1520 x y^4;
vars = {x, y};
```

with

```
polyf = Total[CoefficientRules[poly, vars] /. (p_ -> z_) :> fi[z] Times @@ (vars^p)]
```

$$
-x 2_1 \times 5_1-y^3 2_{11} \times 5_1-x y^4 2_4 \times 5_1 \times 19_1
$$

You turn `polyf` back into the original polynomial with

```
polyf /. Subscript -> Power
(* -10 x - 10240 y^3 - 1520 x y^4 *)
```

This method can be used with @Somos's `fi` function as well if it suits you better.

---

You can also go straight to $\LaTeX$ output and bypass the *Mathematica* typesetting step:

```
stringify1[{x_, 0}] = Nothing;
stringify1[{x_, 1}] := ToString[x];
stringify1[{x_, n_}] := ToString[x] <> "^{" <> ToString[n] <> "}";
stringify[L_] := StringRiffle[stringify1 /@ L, sep]

texints[n_Integer /; n > 0] := "+" <> stringify[FactorInteger[n]]
texints[n_Integer /; n < 0] := "-" <> stringify[FactorInteger[-n]]

texpowers[p_] := stringify[Transpose[{vars, p}]]

texterm[p_, c_] /; DeleteDuplicates[p] == {0} = texints[c];
texterm[p_, 1] := "+" <> texpowers[p];
texterm[p_, c_] := texints[c] <> sep <> texpowers[p];

maketex[poly_, vars1_, sep1_: " \\, "] := 
  Block[{vars = vars1, sep = sep1}, 
    StringTrim[StringJoin[CoefficientRules[poly] /. Rule -> texterm], "+"]]
```

Try it out with your test polynomial:

```
maketex[-10 x - 10240 y^3 - 1520 x y^4, {x, y}]
```

> -2^{4} \, 5 \, 19 \, x \, y^{4}-2 \, 5 \, x-2^{11} \, 5 \, y^{3}

$$
-2^{4} \, 5 \, 19 \, x \, y^{4}-2 \, 5 \, x-2^{11} \, 5 \, y^{3}
$$

Same with a dot between all terms:

```
maketex[-10 x - 10240 y^3 - 1520 x y^4, {x, y}, " \\cdot "]
```

> -2^{4} \cdot 5 \cdot 19 \cdot x \cdot y^{4}-2 \cdot 5 \cdot x-2^{11} \cdot 5 \cdot y^{3}

$$
-2^{4} \cdot 5 \cdot 19 \cdot x \cdot y^{4}-2 \cdot 5 \cdot x-2^{11} \cdot 5 \cdot y^{3}
$$

A three-variable polynomial as a demo:

```
maketex[(a + 2 b + 3 c - 1)^3, {a, b, c}, " \\cdot "]
```

> a^{3}+2 \cdot 3 \cdot a^{2} \cdot b+3^{2} \cdot a^{2} \cdot c-3 
>   \cdot a^{2}+2^{2} \cdot 3 \cdot a \cdot b^{2}+2^{2} \cdot 3^{2} 
>   \cdot a \cdot b \cdot c-2^{2} \cdot 3 \cdot a \cdot b+3^{3} 
>   \cdot a \cdot c^{2}-2 \cdot 3^{2} \cdot a \cdot c+3 \cdot 
>   a+2^{3} \cdot b^{3}+2^{2} \cdot 3^{2} \cdot b^{2} \cdot c-2^{2} 
>   \cdot 3 \cdot b^{2}+2 \cdot 3^{3} \cdot b \cdot c^{2}-2^{2} 
>   \cdot 3^{2} \cdot b \cdot c+2 \cdot 3 \cdot b+3^{3} \cdot 
>   c^{3}-3^{3} \cdot c^{2}+3^{2} \cdot c-1

$$
a^{3}+2 \cdot 3 \cdot a^{2} \cdot b+3^{2} \cdot a^{2} \cdot c-3 
\cdot a^{2}+2^{2} \cdot 3 \cdot a \cdot b^{2}+2^{2} \cdot 3^{2} 
\cdot a \cdot b \cdot c-2^{2} \cdot 3 \cdot a \cdot b+3^{3} 
\cdot a \cdot c^{2}-2 \cdot 3^{2} \cdot a \cdot c+3 \cdot 
a+2^{3} \cdot b^{3}+2^{2} \cdot 3^{2} \cdot b^{2} \cdot c-2^{2} 
\cdot 3 \cdot b^{2}+2 \cdot 3^{3} \cdot b \cdot c^{2}-2^{2} 
\cdot 3^{2} \cdot b \cdot c+2 \cdot 3 \cdot b+3^{3} \cdot 
c^{3}-3^{3} \cdot c^{2}+3^{2} \cdot c-1
$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As I said in a comment on @Somos' answer, I would like output that I can convert easily to LaTeX form and two issues arise with the output form in your answer: (i) the subscripts have to be converted to superscripts (ii) the coefficients come after the monomials.

Comment: If you want to convert to LaTeX at the end, then maybe you'd be better off writing a function that generates LaTeX code directly, instead of generating Mathematica output and using `TeXForm` on it.

Comment: True. But I like eyeballing it first.

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to use `` GroebnerBasis`DistributedTermsList[] `` even if it's *undocumented*, there's a way to get what you want:

```
poly = -2 5 x - 2^11 5 y^3 - 2^4 5 19 x y^4; vars = {x, y};

tl = GroebnerBasis`DistributedTermsList[poly, vars]
   {{{{1, 4}, -1520}, {{1, 0}, -10}, {{0, 3}, -10240}}, {x, y}}
```

The first list is a list of pairs, corresponding to the powers of your variables and their corresponding coefficients. That's what you want.

```
tl = MapAt[FactorInteger, First[tl], {All, 2}];
```

Now that you have factored the coefficients, we need a little helper:

```
myPower[a_, b_] := 
  Which[a === -1, a, b === 0, 1, b === 1, HoldForm[a], True, Power[HoldForm[a], HoldForm[b]]]
```

after which,

```
expr = Total[(Times @@ (myPower @@@ Last[#])) Inner[myPower, vars, First[#], Times] & /@ tl]
```

should yield something like what you want. To turn it back to normal, just evaluate `ReleaseHold[expr]` and you can check that it's the same as `poly`.

Comment: Instead of the undocumented ``GroebnerBasis`DistributedTermsList`` you can use `CoefficientRules` which gives the same information.

Comment: @J. M. is slightly pensive♦ Your last command leads to `Total::normal: Nonatomic expression expected at position 1 in Total[alist].` How should I overcome this?

Comment: @S.Kowalevsky sorry, I forgot to change variable names; try now